# How to generate a confirmation link to confirm correct data for non-salesforce-users?

Tags: email, workflow, confirmation

We have a process in which an external salesperson needs to confirm the amount of his commission. Workflow is something like:

1. The opportunity has status = won
2. A commission is generated
3. An email is send with a confirmation link
4. The user clicks on the link inside the email
5. The commission is updated, setting "Salesperson confirmed commission"-checkbox to `true`

I tried to find something in the direction of public links / email confirmations but I couldn't find any solution.

Is there any way to do this within salesforce or do we need to use an external system for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the link would be possible as all Salesforce pages (other than communities) will require a licence, you could host a landing page externally which could then update Salesforce via an API. The other alternative is you could ask the external user to reply to your email rather than ask them to click a link.

Comment: That's what I thought... thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage an approval process for this. You probably don't want it to exist on the Opportunity itself, rather on a related Commission record.
You'd need automation to kick off the approval process when the Oppty entered Closed-Won, but that shouldn't be terribly hard.

Comment: Wait, non-licensed. Nevermind. This would only work with licensed users.

Comment: Yeah, looks like this is not possible without a license